# Puzzled by different result from "same" type cast, float to int

Tags: c++, gcc, floating-point, type-conversion

If I assign a value to a floating point computation to a variable first, then assign that to an unsigned int with implicit type casting, I get one answer.  But if I assign the same computation directly to the unsigned int, again with implicit type casting, I get a different answer.

Below is sample code I compiled and ran to demonstrate:

```
#include <iostream>



int
main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    float   payloadInTons = 6550.3;


    //  Above, payloadInTons is given a value.
    //  Below, two different ways are used to type cast that same value,
    //  but the results do not match.
    float tempVal = payloadInTons * 10.0;
    unsigned int right = tempVal;
    std::cout << "    right = " << right << std::endl;


    unsigned int rawPayloadN = payloadInTons * 10.0;
    std::cout << "    wrong = " << rawPayloadN << std::endl;


    return 0;
}
```

Does anyone have insight into why "right" is right, and "wrong" is wrong?

By the way, I am using gcc 4.8.2 on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, if it matters.

Comment: It would be a bit more ... impressive if you also included the output you're seeing. On [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/0SMdPN) I got `right = 65503 wrong = 65502`.

Comment: This has the C tag, but it looks like C++.

Comment: It's because of precision. If you multiply both by `100.0` instead of `10.0`, you will understand it.

Comment: @SamuelEdwinWard looks like?

Comment: Good observations, all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using `double` literals. With proper `float` literals, everything's fine.

```
int
main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    float   payloadInTons = 6550.3f;
    float tempVal = payloadInTons * 10.0f;

    unsigned int right = tempVal;
    std::cout << "     right = " << right << std::endl;

    unsigned int rawPayloadN = payloadInTons * 10.0f;
    std::cout << "also right = " << rawPayloadN << std::endl;


    return 0;
}
```

Output :

```
     right = 65503
also right = 65503
```

Comment: Alternatively, one could use doubles everywhere, I think.

Comment: @SamuelEdwinWard of course. As long as it *is* everywhere, such discrepancies won't happen.

Answer (score 6):

After accept answer

This is not a `double` vs. `float` issue.  It is a binary floating-point and conversion to `int/unsigned` issue.

Typical `float` uses [binary32](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) representation with does not give exact representation of values like  6550.3.

```
float payloadInTons = 6550.3;
// payloadInTons has the exact value of `6550.2998046875`.
```

---

Multiplying by `10.0`, below, insures the calculation is done with at least `double` precision with an exact result of `65502.998046875`.  The product is then converted back to `float`.  The `double` value is not exactly representable in `float` and so is rounded to the best `float` with an exact value of `65503.0`.  Then `tempVal` converts `right` as desired with a value of `65503`.

```
float tempVal = payloadInTons * 10.0;
unsigned int right = tempVal;
```

---

Multiplying by `10.0`, below, insures the calculation is done with at least `double` precision with an exact result of `65502.998046875` just as before.  This time, the value is converted directly to `unsigned rawPayloadN` with the undesired with a value of `65502`.  This is because the value in truncated and not rounded.

```
unsigned int rawPayloadN = payloadInTons * 10.0;
```

---

The first “worked” because of the conversion was `double` to `float` to `unsigned`.  This involves 2 conversions with is usually *bad*.  In this case, 2 wrongs made a right.

---

**Solution**

Had code tried `float payloadInTons = 6550.29931640625;` (the next smallest `float` number) both result would have been `65502`.

The "right” way to convert a floating point value to some integer type is often to *round* the result and then perform the type conversion.

```
float tempVal = payloadInTons * 10.0;
unsigned int right = roundf(tempVal);
```

---

Note: This entire issue is complication by the value of  `FLT_EVAL_METHOD`.  If user’s value is non-zero, floating point calculation may occur at higher precision than expected.

```
printf("FLT_EVAL_METHOD %d\n", (int) FLT_EVAL_METHOD);
```

Comment: I understand your explanation, and like the deterministic use of roundf() for future use.

Comment: @donjuedo The point is that using proper `float` literals may not solve the problem.  Depending on `FLT_EVAL_METHOD`, `payloadInTons * 10.0f` and `payloadInTons * 10.0` may result in the exact same code.  The primary issue is that values near `6550.3` are expected to have a result of `65503`.  This will not occur with using "proper literals" but by using rounding.

Comment: Right.  For me, there are two points, the one I stated (why it's different), and the one I didn't, but you helped me with (how to make it reliable).  The first had to do with my incorrect premise, that all the computation was done with float.  I could see how conversion to int could be flawed, but missed how two ways of using float got 2 answers.  One actually used doubles I was not aware of, hence the difference.  I agree with you, that using "proper literals" is not the robust way to get the right result every time.